# Grouped bar chart with label in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, label, shared-libraries, chart.js, bar-chart

I need to recreate a chart very similar to this one:

[image]

While researching I found this **example**:

https://codepen.io/bencarmichael/pen/XeYJXJ

```
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "American Express",
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      borderColor: "red",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [3, 5, 6, 7,3, 5, 6, 7] // I need labels on this values
    }
  ]
```

It shows grouped bar charts. But it's lacking a label per bar. If it's not possible on Chart.js, it can be any other library.

Comment: Is there any solution found? I require exact graph you have shown in question.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

> View result in full screen mode
>
> this is copied from the example you provided in you Question

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: [
    "Absence of OB",
    "Closeness",
    "Credibility",
    "Heritage",
    "M Disclosure",
    "Provenance",
    "Reliability",
    "Transparency"
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "American Express",
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      borderColor: "red",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [3, 5, 6, 7,3, 5, 6, 7],
      
    },
    {
      label: "Mastercard",
      backgroundColor: "lightblue",
      borderColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [4, 7, 3, 6, 10,7,4,6]
    },
    {
      label: "Paypal",
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      borderColor: "green",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [10,7,4,6,9,7,3,10]
    },
    {
      label: "Visa",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      borderColor: "orange",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [6,9,7,3,10,7,4,6]
    }
  ]
};

var chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    position: "top"
  },
 "hover": {
                "animationDuration": 0
            },
   legend: {
                "display": false
            },
            tooltips: {
                "enabled": true
            },
  "animation": {
                "duration": 1,
                "onComplete": function () {
                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                      debugger
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                             var data = dataset.data[index];
                          ctx.font = '10pt Verdana';

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(0,500);
ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
var rText = 'My test value ='+data ;
ctx.fillText(rText , 90,  bar._model.x+5);
ctx.restore();
                        });
                    });
                }
            },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Chart.js Bar Chart"
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartData,
    options: chartOptions
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added it and I can't see any difference. Reading the code it seems to generate a legend when I hover the mouse. Is that right? The problem is that I need a label to be present at all times, since the chart will be printed.

Comment: I have removed hover effect and tooltip because the chart refreshed on hover (to generate tooltip). and the code is perfectly working on codepen example that you mentioned in your question

Comment: Thank you, but I need the label to be under the bar, not on top. And with a customizable text, not the value.

Comment: @Areks I have modified my answer

Comment: @Areks you can generate your labels by customizing **meta.data.forEach** loop

Comment: Yes. I have already modified to display what I need. Any ideas about how to show the label under the bar? Instead of on top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189839/discussion-between-zulqarnain-jalil-and-areks).

Comment: @Areks i have modified the answer